# In Castle Windsor, can a component have it's lifecycle bound to a component that it is not a direct dependency of?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Given a set of objects with the following dependency structure (using constructor injection):

IWidget *depends on* IWidgetDependency *depends on* IDependencyConfiguration

Is it possible to set the lifecycle of the IDependencyConfiguration implementations so that they are bound to specific IWidget implementations, even if I want to use the same IWidgetDependency implementation in multiple places?

Here's the code; it will resolve the FooWidget correctly, but will fail to resolve the BarWidget and I don't understand why:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For<FooWidget>(), Component.For<BarWidget>());

container.Register(Component.For<IWidgetDependency>().ImplementedBy<WidgetDependency>().LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(
    Component.For<IDependencyConfiguration>().ImplementedBy<FooConfiguration>().LifestyleBoundTo<FooWidget>(),
    Component.For<IDependencyConfiguration>().ImplementedBy<BarConfiguration>().LifestyleBoundTo<BarWidget>());

// I expect to resolve a FooWidget that contains a WidgetDependency that contains a FooConfiguration
var fooWidget = container.Resolve<FooWidget>(); // Works fine

// I expect to resolve a BarWidget that contains a WidgetDependency that contains a BarConfiguration
var barWidget = container.Resolve<BarWidget>(); // Scope was not available for 'FooConfiguration'
```

Comment: Could you share your constructor / public properties of FooWidget and BarWidget and WidgetDependency ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how `BoundTo` lifestyles work. A bound lifestyle just means the lifestyle of one component (child) is bound to the existence of another (parent), it has no impact on dependency resolution.

I don't know of an easy way to achieve what you want, my first instinct was to look at the `DependsOn` functionality, but out of the box, that can only bind dependencies to the target component, not the targets other dependencies.

I did find a way to check for `DependsOn` dependencies from the root component when resolving a nested dependency using a factory method. It works for your scenario, but isn't particularly reusable.

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    Component.For<IDependencyConfiguration>().LifestyleTransient()
             .UsingFactoryMethod(ResolveRootDependency<IDependencyConfiguration>));

container.Register(
    Component.For<FooConfiguration>().LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<BarConfiguration>().LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(
    Component.For<FooWidget>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IDependencyConfiguration, FooConfiguration>()),
    Component.For<BarWidget>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IDependencyConfiguration, BarConfiguration>()));

container.Register(Component.For<IWidgetDependency>().ImplementedBy<WidgetDependency>().LifestyleTransient());

// I expect to resolve a FooWidget that contains a WidgetDependency that contains a FooConfiguration
var fooWidget = container.Resolve<FooWidget>(); // Works fine

// I expect to resolve a BarWidget that contains a WidgetDependency that contains a BarConfiguration
var barWidget = container.Resolve<BarWidget>(); // Works fine
```

`ResolveRootDependency` is defined as:

```
private static TDependencyType ResolveRootDependency<TDependencyType>(IKernel kernel, CreationContext context)
{
    foreach (var dependency in context.Handler.ComponentModel.Dependencies)
    {
        if (dependency.DependencyKey == typeof(TDependencyType).AssemblyQualifiedName)
        {
            return kernel.Resolve<TDependencyType>(dependency.ReferencedComponentName);
        }
    }

    return kernel.Resolve<TDependencyType>();
}
```